# Keep the first X words in list elements whilst keeping the list one dimension?

Tags: python, list

I've a list which elements are comformed by words. In example:

```
listA = ["Hello, I'm Margaret and I'm 32 years old", 
"Howdy, I'm Louis and I'm 35 years old",
"Greetings, I'm Veronica, I come from Canada",
"Night, I'm Pepe and I'm a mexican singer"]
```

However, I want to use a list comprehension to keep only the first three words of every element in the list, so the result is:

```
ListA = ["Hello, I'm Margaret",
"Howdy, I'm Louis",
"Greetings, I'm Veronica",
"Night, I'm Pepe"]
```

I've tried using the following list comprehension:

```
ListA = [i.split()[0:2] for i in ListA]
```

But this results in a list of lists, which is not desired:

```
ListA = [["Hello, I'm Margaret"],
["Howdy, I'm Louis"],
["Greetings, I'm Veronica"],
["Night, I'm Pepe"]]
```

Is using split() the correct approach? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make sure you join the split string again: `ListA = [' '.join(i.split()[0:2]) for e in ListA if e]`

Comment: Hello Reut! Please post this as an answer, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just make sure to join the string back:

```
ListA = [' '.join(e.split()[0:2]) for e in ListA]
```

Also you may want `[0:3]` and not `[0:2]`, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to `join` the splitted list back to a string:

```
ListA = [' '.join(i.split()[0:2]) for i in ListA]
```